# Auto Pagination combine with Auto Refresh Div every X seconds

Tags: javascript, datatables, codeigniter-3

I'm setting up a datatables and i want to display it on monitor so that i need the datatables can refresh div and also auto pagination to the next page at the same time. When the div refresh it canceled the auto pagination and back to the first page. Please help me.

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var table = $('.data').DataTable({
                "searching": false,
                "info": false,
                "lengthChange": false
            });
            setInterval(function(){ 
            var info = table.page.info();
            var pageNum = (info.page < info.pages) ? info.page + 1 : 1;
            table.page(pageNum).draw(false);    
            }, 5000);  
        });

        $(document).ready(function() {
            setInterval(function () {
                $('#test').load(window.location.href + ' #test');
            }, 3000);
        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try reinitializing the `Datatable` like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  initDataTable();
  setInterval(function() {
    $('#test').load(window.location.href + ' #test', initDataTable);
  }, 3000);
});

function initDataTable() {  
  var table = $('.data').DataTable({
    "searching": false,
    "info": false,
    "lengthChange": false
  });
  setInterval(function() {
    var info = table.page.info();
    var pageNum = (info.page < info.pages) ? info.page + 1 : 1;
    table.page(pageNum).draw(false);
  }, 5000);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Use global variable for page number

```
var info;
var pageNum = 1;
var pageInterval;

$(document).ready(function() {
  initDataTable();
  setInterval(function() {
    $('#test').load(window.location.href + ' #test', initDataTable);
  }, 3000);
});

function initDataTable() {
  clearInterval(pageInterval)
  var table = $('.data').DataTable({
    "searching": false,
    "info": false,
    "lengthChange": false
  });
  pageInterval = setInterval(function() {
    info = table.page.info();
    pageNum = (pageNum + 1) % info.pages
    table.page(pageNum).draw(false);
  }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: reinitailizing makes the div refresh but the auto pagination still not working...is there any solution? all i want is to make the div refresh and the auto pagination is working too without back to the first page

Comment: @MasterData It's updated and It's almost impossible without `pen` or `fiddle`.